# Is there any mathematical formula to calculate padding to be applied for any element in html/css?

Tags: html, css

Is there any mathematical formula to calculate padding to be applied for any element in html/css?

For eg.: If i have a card and i want to give it a padding, so is there a mathematical formula i can apply to calculate the padding for that card component to make it more visually appealing and consistent with overall design of a webpage.

Comment: Please be more detailed what you mean and share an example. For me it is not clear what the formula should calculate.

Comment: I mean you could probably write some kind of algorithm that can solve that for you but it will only work for a certain case defined by you. There is no "One for all" mathematical formula to solve your padding issue. Just try to implement responsive layout with grid and responsive design of each element alignment with flexbox to make the page be good and ready for whatever screen size

Comment: @biberman Oh, i tried to be as clear as possible, so to make it more clear what i want is:

if i have a width and height of a div, i want to do something like this to get a padding:

magic_number = getPadding(width, height);

padding: magic_number* padding;

Answer (score 2):

Actually **No**. There are no mathematical formulae to calculate what padding to give. It all depends on the visualization of the UI Developer. If you feel a padding of 5px looks better than 2px in your website, then use 2px. It all depends on you and your views on how it should look.

You can look at other webpages to get an Idea of how much padding makes it visually appealing. It is similar for all other properties (margins, borders, outlines, shadows, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I am understanding your question right, but you **calculate** your padding in your CSS.

**Normal CSS:**

```
.element {
   padding: 20px;
}
```

**Calculated CSS:**

```
.element {
  padding: calc(10% - 80px);
}
```

[Here's a link to some documentation for it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc())